# Undefined method in Code Igniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, methods, view, model

I've problem in CodeIgniter framework,

1. **Controller**  :

   ```
    public function tambah() {   
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('judul', 'Judul', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('deskripsi', 'Deskripsi','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('isi', 'Isi', 'required');


    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
         $data=array('title'=>'Menambah Berita',
                     'isi'  =>'admin/berita/tambah_berita'
                    );
          $this->load->view('admin/layout/wrapper',$data); 
    }else{
         $tag = url_title($this->input->post('judul'), 'dash', TRUE);
         $data = array(

               'judul'     => $this->input->post('judul'),
               'tag'       => $tag,//edited
               'deskripsi' => $this->input->post('deskripsi'),
               'isi'       => $this->input->post('isi'),
               'status'    => $this->input->post('status'),
               'id_admin'  => $this->input->post('id_admin')
           );
   $this->berita_model->tambah($data);
   redirect(base_url().'admin/berita/');
   ```

   }
   }
2. Model :

   ```
    public function tambah($data) {
         return $this->db->insert('lm_destination', $data);
       }
   ```
3. View : view file has fixed.
   Those code yields :
   **Fatal error: Call to undefined method Berita_model::tambah() in C:.\application\controllers\admin\file.php on line 41**

Anybody can help me fix it? thanks

Comment: maybe show us some codes on Berita_model?

Comment: you have load the model   $this->load->model('berita_model');

Answer (score 1):

You must write

```
$this->load->model('berita_model');
```

before use

```
$this->berita_model->tambah($data);
```

Comment: @Rian Sociopreneur, If this answer your question, please click acceptance button on the left

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help YOu

1. **Controller**  :

   ```
    public function tambah() {   
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('judul', 'Judul', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('deskripsi', 'Deskripsi','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('isi', 'Isi', 'required');


    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
         $data=array('title'=>'Menambah Berita',
                     'isi'  =>'admin/berita/tambah_berita'
                    );
          $this->load->view('admin/layout/wrapper',$data); 
    }else{
         $tag = url_title($this->input->post('judul'), 'dash', TRUE);
         $data = array(

               'judul'     => $this->input->post('judul'),
               'tag'       => $tag,//edited
               'deskripsi' => $this->input->post('deskripsi'),
               'isi'       => $this->input->post('isi'),
               'status'    => $this->input->post('status'),
               'id_admin'  => $this->input->post('id_admin')
           );
     $this->load->model('berita_model');
   $this->berita_model->tambah($data);
   redirect(base_url().'admin/berita/');
   ```

   }
   }
2. Model :

   ```
    public function tambah($data) {
          $this->db->insert('lm_destination', $data);
            return true;
       }
   ```